# Continue div background while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want my div background to scroll be the height of the window even when you scroll down.

However It seems to only be the height of the original window size. When I scroll down I am seeing the background of my body.

I've searched this site for similar questions and all I'm finding is to use height: 100%;
but that is not working.

Here is my CSS code:

```
div#graycontainer {
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 50px;
            width:1000px;
            background-color: #D9D9D9;
            height: 100%;
            /*box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px #888888;*/
            /*border: 3px solid #888889;*/
            border-radius: 1px;
}
```

I don't believe there is any problem with my other code and using this site as a last resort.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you want here. Your CSS block isn't enough to determine what you are after, and the description of your issue needs to be more clear.

Comment: I want my background-color to continue while scrolling down throughout the page. How it is now doesn't work.

Comment: post your HTML markup or preferably a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem. Also please edit your title since it has nothing to do with your question

Comment: This should work if you take out `height: 100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `height: 100%;` will only create the image with the height of the browser. What you want to do is something that doesn't depend on the scroll position. In the case that you want the image to stay in place on scroll, you might use `position`. First use `position: fixed;` This will set the image at its very position. And after that you can use the z-index to make sure it stays above the background. Use this:

```
#image_at_back {  
  margin: auto;  
  margin-top: 50px;  
  width:1000px;  
  background-color: #D9D9D9;  
  height: 100%;  
  /*box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px #888888;*/  
  /*border: 3px solid #888889;*/  
  border-radius: 1px;  
  position: fixed;  
  z-index: -1; // to make it a background
}
```

You can read more [here](http://w3schools.com).

When you add the fixed position, try to add some text to make the scroll bar visible. Then when you scroll it, the image stays at its position.